# Uninstall Ruby on Rails cpanel server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uninstallation, cpanel, whm

I'm sitting here with a cPanel server, and I want to uninstall ruby, and ruby on rails.

I can see there is /scripts/installruby, but not a remove.

Does anyone know how I can uninstall ruby and rails from my server? So I can free up the space given I don't use it anyway?

Please note that I do have full root access to the server!

Comment: Could you add in more info about what ruby you are running? Like: `which ruby` then find out how Ruby is run on your Web server (passenger.. unicorn.. mongrel.. etc)

Comment: Tigraine: This is the version I'm running:
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you run. If Ruby was installed through a packet manager like `apt` you can simply use that to uninstall it.

`apt-get remove ruby`

If the ruby install was a build from source you obviously either want to find the sources and do a `make uninstall` or you simply delete the folders where ruby is at (`which ruby` gives you the paths)

Ruby on Rails is only a gem inside ruby - so deleting the ruby folder with the gem folder in it will also remove rails. Make sure to clean up your path of any references to the `ruby/bin` and `gem/bin` folders and you should be good.

Then you have to figure out what application server was running ruby on your box. And uninstall those seperatly ([passenger](http://www.modrails.com/), [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/), [mongrel](http://mongrel2.org/) etc)..

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I know that the ruby is installed by using the /scripts/installruby command in cpanel, and content of the installruby is following:

http://pastebin.com/kqGKFHdB

Comment: You could try reversing what the script does.. but I doubt you can just uninstall ruby using the cpanel stuff unless you find a uninstall-ruby script that was written to revert the script you ran..